# Fetching time from datetimepicker to mysql time data type

Tags: vb.net

I have datetimepicker with custom 24hour format HH:mm:ss
selection of hours only

then i declared mydtIncidentTime as DateAndtime

```
    mydtIncidentTime = dttimepicker.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

Im saving time in 24hour format only
on my saving time to mysql (mysql data type is TIME)

```
    str_to_date('" & Me.mydtIncidentTime & "', '%H:%i%s')
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

you can use TIME_FORMAT() function of MySQL.

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(timeout_pm, '%h:%i:%s %p') time_12h
  FROM dtr
 WHERE ...
```

You can find [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cc34/2) demo